# In TensorFlow, how to reshape a tensor in a specific axis?

Tags: tensorflow

Now i have a tensor with shape (3*2, 2) look like

[image]

and i want to reshape it with the shape (3, 2*2) with the specific axis like following:

[image]

what should i do? The default `tf.reshape()` will reshape it to

[image]

**SOLUTION**： I found that use `slice` in tensorflow and tf.concat() can solve the problem.You can slice sub-tensors and concat them which solve my problem exactly

Comment: Could you share the code using the slice and concat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code and got the result that you need. But not sure whether the number of steps can be reduced.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [[1, 2],
     [3,4],
     [5,6],
     [7,8],
     [9,10],
     [11,12]]

a = tf.reshape(x,[-1,6])
b = tf.split(a,3, 1)
c = tf.reshape(b,[-1,4])

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[6, 2], name='input')

with tf.Session() as sess:
      c =  sess.run(c, feed_dict={X: x})
      print(c)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it works, but i found that `slice` in tensorflow and tf.concat can also solve my problem, anyway, thanks for your help:)